# Exposing SOAP backend as a REST API WSO2 api manager 4.1.0 using the generate API's implementation is throwing error 500 during the creation

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wsdl, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to expose a soap backend as rest using wso2 apim and during so I followed the steps :

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeMEo.png)

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJGG3.png)

the error that is shown in the log in the following :
[log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6b9c.png)

and here is the link to the wsdl file I used :
https://blackboard.mynaseej.net/webapps/bb-data-integration-lis-final-BBLEARN/services/PersonManagementServiceSyncService.wsdl

PS : the WSDL file is valid and it's already been used in my company for previous integrations.

Comment: What errors do you see in wso2carbon.logs?

Comment: Also, it seems in APIM 4.1.0 this feature is deprecated. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-rest-api/generate-rest-api-from-soap-backend/